# Passing the value of one option to another

Tags: vim

A rather silly Vim question, but I've something to do, and I'm not finding the solution in help. So here goes ...

(this is just an example, I'm not necessarily interested in *guifont* and *printfont* only)

```
set guifont?
```

gives out ...

How can I say,

```
set printfont=guifont
```

i.e. pass the string you get from `guifont?` to `printfont`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let &printfont = &guifont
```

seems to work fine.

Comment: ugh, figures it had to be something elemental. thanks lucapette!